# Best practice of loading a huge image dataset for ML

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset

I'm playing around with a image dataset in kanggle (https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/paddy-disease-classification/data). In this dataset, there are about 10000 images with 480*640 resolution.
When I try to load this dataset by following code,

```py
for (label, file) in dataset_file_img(dataset_path)
    image = load_img_into_tensor(file)
    data.append(image/255)
    data_label.append(label)
```

it consume about 20GB of RAM.

What is the best practice of loading a dataset like this?
Any help will/would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use various components available under `tf.data` module. See [Building Input Pipelines with `tf.data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following from `keras`:

1. `ImageDataGenerator` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)
2. `image_dataset_from_directory` function [here](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have enough GPU computing power, ImageDataGenerator will probably give you a bottleneck. As suggested by [Shubham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13546426/shubham-panchal), try to use `tf.data`, which is the best option as far as I know.